# Чи ми можемо вживати слово "Виключення"?

Tags: вживання-слів, росіянізм, віддієслівні-іменники

Є речення з статті по психології, яке мені потрібно використати у своїй статті, але я не певна, що можна вживати слово "виключення":

> Це є єдиним виключенням з даного типу поведінки.

Answer (score 1):

Для Вашого речення краще вжити слово **"виняток"**.

Визначення з СУМ-20

> **[ВИКЛЮЧЕННЯ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=9092&page=321)** я, с. Дія за знач. ви́ключити і ви́ключитися 1.
>   *Спроба позбавити політичні партії посередницьких функцій на виборах у США вилилась у виключення назв партій із виборчих бюлетенів* (з
>   публіц. літ.); *Підозрілим здалося йому виключення Мотла з
>   Полтавського педагогічного інституту: після однорічного вчителювання
>   на Донбасі його було зараховано до Харківського університету* (О.
>   Іваненко).
>
> **[ВИНЯТОК](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=9890&page=340)** тку, ч. Відхилення від звичайного, від загального
>   правила. *Винятки, очевидячки, минаємо* (М. Коцюбинський);   **(1)**
>   Без ви́нятку, перев. зі сл. всі, все – не виключаючи нікого, нічого з
>   певного кола, загалу; підряд. *Досі вона була доброзичливою до всіх
>   без винятку* (О. Гончар);  **(2)** За ви́нятком кого, чого –
>   виключаючи кого-, що-небудь із якогось кола, загалу; крім. *Всі, за
>   винятком Бойчука, здивовано дивилися на свого шкіпера* (М. Трублаїні).

З сайту [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/viklyuchennya-y-vinyatok)

> **Виключення** – усування, припинення дії: виключення зі списку, з університету, з організації.
>
> **Виняток** – відхилення від правила, від чогось звичайного.
>   [image]

Отже, краще написати **"Це є єдиним *винятком* з даного типу поведінки."**